# Как правильней подключить асинхронно внешний скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html

Встречаю разные варианты асинхронного подключения внешних скриптов:

```
<script async ...></script>
<script async="true" ...></script>
<script async="async" ...></script>
```

Подскажите в чем тут разница и какой вариант правильнее?

Answer (score 1):

Все эти варианты должны работать, но разницы фактически нет, т к браузер во всех случаях читает только имя атрибута - **async**.
[Скрипты: async, defer](https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer)

***true*** и ***false*** встречаются в коде JS, но не бывают в качестве значений атрибутов внутри тегов HTML.

По такому же примеру часто ошибочно пишут

`<audio controls="controls" autoplay="true"></audio>`, и прочее.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации, нужно указать только `async`, то есть `<script async ...></script>`: [HTML  async Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp).